# How to access WebGLRenderTarget texture content

Tags: three.js, render-to-texture, rendertarget

So I render a scene to a texture and then I need to process the texture in js and either modify the contents or make a new texture from an array of values.
It seems like I need to get the WebGL context and interface directly with WebGL to accomplish this. Does anybody know the best way to do this?

Comment: It would help if you added some of your code.

Comment: what do you mean by process the texture/modify the contents/make a new texture from an array ? I suppose what you need is rendertarget + fragment shader

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up just getting the webGL context from the renderer and calling gl.readPixels()

```
var gl = renderer.getContext();
var framebuffer = renderTarget.__webglFramebuffer;
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
var data = new Uint8Array(renderTarget.width * renderTarget.height * 4);
gl.readPixels(0,0,renderTarget.width,renderTarget.heigh,gl.RGBA,gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,data);
```

(renderTarget is an instance of THREE.WebGLRenderTarget)

Comment: Instead, you can use the method `WebGLRenderer.readRenderTargetPixels( renderTarget, x, y, width, height, buffer )`.

Comment: using either method results in an array with a strong bias towards either 0 or 255.  Not much in between.  I'm expecting much different floats.  Any idea why these aren't the floats I'm expecting?  I even added { premultipliedAlpha : false } to my Renderer

Comment: pixels are defined as sets of 4 bytes. For R, G, B and A values. if you want floats, you'll have to map each entry in this array by 255. It's probably best to do that inline with the processing function rather than mapping the array all at once.